# Video goes black after a second or two

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, youtube, youtube-javascript-api

I'm currently using the Youtube JavaScript API to embed videos into my webpage to control a playlist that i have. The error i seem to be getting over and over is that the video itself goes black right after loading the title, play icon and loading icon. It all seems for a second or two that the video is going to be played. But after the title slides up to allow the video to play all i get is a black background. The title is shown just fine along with the youtube text up in the right corner. But the video itself is not played.

This problem is only happening on the iPhone from what i can see. Works perfectly on Android and PC.

```
    var playlistDescription = [];
    var playlist = [];
    var tag = document.createElement("script");

    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    var youtubePlayer;
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        playlist.push("youtubevideoid");

        $(".video-list-item").each( function() {
            if ($(this).data("id") != "youtubevideoid") {
                playlist.push($(this).data("id"));
            }
        })

        youtubePlayer = new YT.Player("youtube-player", {
            videoId: "youtubevideoid",
            height: "378",
            width: "672",
            playerVars: {
                "color1": "#046a3b",
                "color2": "#faa820"
            },
            events: {
                "onReady": onPlayerReady,
                "onStateChange": onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });


    }  

    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        youtubePlayer.loadPlaylist(playlist);
    }

    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == -1 || event.data == 0) {
            var playlistDescriptionItem = playlistDescription[youtubePlayer.getPlaylistIndex()];
            $(".divSubHeadline").text(playlistDescriptionItem.title);
            $(".pageContent span").text(playlistDescriptionItem.description);
        }
    }
```

This is the script i uses to load the youtube playlist.
The playlist variable contains the playlist items that the video is connected to.

Cant get it to work on jsfiddle - Might just be me.. So i pasted the script in here.

Comment: could you post sample on jsfiddle

Comment: Couldn't get jsfiddle to display the video. Pasted the javascript source in a code field.

Comment: could you post complete javascript and html code

Comment: This is the complete JavaScript. The only HTML there is, is a container with the id youtube-player and two other divs for the title and description.

Comment: do you need to update your flash ? http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/

Comment: Sry bout it, i seem to have forgot to actually mention this is for iphone. Happens both on 4/5. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0):

i had exactly the same problem. I found the answer here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/youtube-api-gdata/ios$20autoplay/youtube-api-gdata/Fr39edfAKgs/FxfdHIu3H8MJ

"Warning: To prevent unsolicited downloads over cellular networks at the user’s expense, embedded media cannot be played automatically in Safari on iOS—the user always initiates playback. A controller is automatically supplied on iPhone or iPod touch once playback in initiated, but for iPad you must either set the controls attribute or provide a controller using JavaScript."

Try the code below:

```
youtubePlayer = new YT.Player("youtube-player", {
        videoId: "youtubevideoid",
        height: "378",
        width: "672",
        playerVars: {
            "autoplay": 1,
            "controls": 1,
            "showinfo": 0
        },
        events: {
            "onReady": onPlayerReady,
            "onStateChange": onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });


}  

function onPlayerReady(event) {
    // do whatever you need to do here
    // but don't call:
    // event.target.playVideo();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems.

My problem seemed was my onPlayerReady function:

```
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
}
```

It worked perfectly after i removed:

```
event.target.playVideo();
```

If interessted, here's my entire code:

```
player = new YT.Player(playerId, {
  height: '410',
  width: '820',
  videoId: videoId,
  playerVars: {
      "autoplay": 1,
      "controls": 1,
      "showinfo": 0
  },
  events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': onIntroPlayerStateChange
  }
});

function onPlayerReady(event) {

}

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data === 0) {
        console.log("Movie ended - go get some fresh air");
    }
}
```

Autoplay, doesn't seem to work on IOS7 though :-(